# Rendering issue with saga while invoke `call` effect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-saga

I have something like this

```
yield takeLetest('SOME_ACTION', function* (action){
  const res = yield call(api, params);
  // here triggers rerender in react component
  yield put({ type: 'ACTION_TO_STORE', res })
})
```

and the question is: Why is this happening if no action was dispatched to the store between `call` and `put`?

Comment: Can we see the whole component, please?

Comment: @Hinrich i don't even have those store node dependency (from this api call) in component

Comment: But you wrote about triggering of rerender in some react component, right? We need some more code insight to be able to help.